# Disable controls in repeater from page to web user control

Tags: asp.net, repeater, asp.net-4.0, webusercontrol

I have a user control in which I have `Repeater` control and inside this there are two image button.

I want to be able to set the visibility to false for the image buttons.

I am able to set visibility to false for the other controls of the user control like this...

```
this.Comment1.FindControl("btnAddNote").Visible = false;
```

...but am unable to set the visibility false for the 2 image button inside `ItemTemplate` of `Repeater`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're dealing with controls inside of a repeater the FindControl method is not able to access controls in the item template. To do this you have to loop through each of the repeater's items and use FindControl on the RepeaterItem.

Since your repeater is inside the user control I'd suggest making a method on your usercontrol like this, and calling that from the page.

```
//user control
public void HideNotes(){
   foreach (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater1.Items)
      ri.FindControl("btnAddNote").Visible = false;
}

//page
void btn_hide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   this.Comment1.HideNotes();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am trying to do that but when I am accessing the function from page load, it is showing that repeater has no item. but it does have 2 rows

Comment: Has your repeater been databound by the time you try to loop through its items?